# laser headlights in BMW?

Tags: bmw, headlight

I heard they were making some laser headlights a while back but then I heard they were banned in the U.S is it still banned or are they used around now?

Comment: This is a question Google can answer easily.

Comment: @Moab I usually like your comments, but this is pretty useless.

Comment: Contact the Government Department responsible for regulations for cars...

Comment: @DavidLively and so is your lame question which shows No research effort..

Answer (score 1):

> It took a couple of years for this technology to be approved for use on U.S. roads, and it is currently available (and legal) on cars such as the X5, the new 4, 7 or the 8 series.

https://www.autoevolution.com/news/this-is-how-bmw-s-laserlight-technology-works-150098.html

> The high end model BMWs come equipped as this technology becomes more perfected, but as the years go on, entry level models will include it. In specific, this technology is available in the United States for the BMW i8 Coupe and Roadster, and is an option this year on the M850i xDrive Coupe and the X5.
>
> BMW Laserlight headlights feature thin blue strips along the inside of the headlight housing, with some models, like the X5, featuring blue strips across the lens.
>
> In short, as government regulations become solidified, the technology will be found more and more on various models.

https://www.bmwakron.com/bmw_laser_lights----bmw-dealership-near-me.html